# Doctrine Query Builder count ManyToMany

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have an entity Offer. Offer has a ManyToMany Relationship to Files.
Now I want to have all Offers, that have files -> Count(offer.files) > 0.

I tried it like this, but doesn't work:

```
$this->repository->createQueryBuilder('offer')
            ->addSelect('COUNT(offer.files) as files')
            ->having('files > 1')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [**inner join**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) with the association and [group by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) the root entity offer:

```
->innerJoin('offer.files', 'files')
```

> The INNER JOIN keyword selects records that have matching values in both tables.

Then you can:

```
->addSelect('COUNT(files) as total')
->having('total > 1')
->groupBy('offer')
```

If you do not need the total in the result, you can define it as **HIDDEN**, change the 1st line above as:

```
->addSelect('COUNT(files) as HIDDEN total')
```

[Inner join in detail](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-inner-joins.htm)
[Doctrine query builder](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html)

Answer (score 11):

Actually you do not need a join. Doctrine has built in `SIZE` [DQL function](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions) for that.

> SIZE(collection) - Return the number of elements in the specified collection

So you could use it like this:

```
$this->repository->createQueryBuilder('offer')
    ->addSelect('SIZE(offer.files) as files')
    ->having('files > 1')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```